# Problems building ICU samples under VS2008

Tags: c++, icu

I tried to build ICU4C sample "[uncv](http://icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/samples/)" using visual studio 2008 without success

1. I added the header directories (Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories)
2. referenced the lib folder (Configuration Properties > Linker > Additional Library Directories)
3. I added the bin folder the PATH environment variable

After building the errors of kind "unresolved external symbol ... referenced in function ..." is shown. **Am i missing anything ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did indeed miss one step -- you need to actually link to the ICU .lib files rather than just tell the linker where they reside. See [.Lib Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822%28VS.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: it really worked but it shows error during run saying that "MSVCR100" is not found. I googled "MSVCR100.dll" , downloaded it and it seems to work now

Comment: @Abdelwahed : That implies that you're your app (with VC++ 2008) to libraries built with VC++ 2010. This is **not** a good thing, and if it appears to work for you, it's only out of sheer luck. You need ICU binaries built with the same version of VC++ as you're using.

Comment: You should be able to use VS2010 (it's free) and target it to create ICU libraries for 2008